# How to print gc traces by embedding gctrace env with go binary?

Tags: go

I have a simple program that prints hello world. To emit gc trace information am using following command by directly running the main.go file

```
$ GODEBUG=gctrace=1 go run main.go
gc 1 @0.011s 1%: 0.020+1.3+0.056 ms clock, 0.24+0.62/0.38/1.6+0.67 ms cpu, 4->4->0 MB, 5 MB goal, 12 P
Hello Playground
gc 2 @0.021s 0%: 0.004+0.55+0.006 ms clock, 0.052+0.12/0.36/0.49+0.079 ms cpu, 4->4->0 MB, 5 MB goal, 12 P
```

**Question**

Is there a way to build the binary and yet print the gctraces while running the binary directly and **without** explicitly passing the GODEBUG=gctrace=1 to the binary?

(OR)

How to build binary with GODEBUG=gctrace=1 without explicitly mentioning at runtime ?

```
  $ go build -O main  // (builds binary main)      
  $ ./main  // doesn't print gc trace information
   Hello Playground
```

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
)

func main() {
        fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}
```

Comment: You have to set it in the runtime environment, so wrap the binary in something to set the variable as needed. Setting up the correct environment for running a process is a fairly normal exercise. Note that your first example is also printing the gctrace stats from the go tool before it runs your program.

Comment: @JimB actually i mistakenly omitted gctrace and hello playground output in my program. I've edited code snippet output now. Can you please be more specific about wrapping the binary with need env?  If you have any example can you please let me know. Thank you.